# Que faz o «eu» em «eu custa-me a crer tais boatos»? Ou nem sequer lá devia estar?

Tags: concordância-verbal, sintaxe

***Custa-me a crer*** ou ***a mim custa-me a crer*** não levantam espiga, mas ***eu custa-me*** parece violar a concordância verbal. No entanto, eu soam-me perfeitamente naturais esta e outras construções tais. E têm pergaminhos literários. Eis vários exemplos, com ênfase minha:

> ***Eu custa-me*** a crer taes boatos […]  [[Revista do Instituto Histórico e Geográphico do Rio Grande do Sul, 1929]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6As0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22eu%20custa-me%20a%20crer%22&dq=%22eu%20custa-me%20a%20crer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE9uDtoYLNAhVrL8AKHTchDrwQ6AEILjAD)
>
> ***Você sucedeu-lhe*** o quer que seja de muito bom! [[Eça de Queiroz, *Os Maias*, 1888]](http://figaro.fis.uc.pt/queiros/obras/Maias/Maias_20001210.pdf)
>
> «***Eu custa-me*** incomodar assim os senhores, mas vimos em serviço.›› [[José Carlos Barros, *Um Amigo para o Inverno*, 2013.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7k52isihiKUC&pg=PT34&dq=%22eu%20custa-me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj944vFqoLNAhXMKMAKHbgsB1gQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=%22eu%20custa-me%22&f=false)

E é coisa antiga. Este exemplo já era antigo quando o Almeida Garrett o incluiu no [*Romanceiro e Cancioneiro Geral* de 1843:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EapLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=%22a%20porteira%20o%20que%20lhe%20importa%22&source=bl&ots=6_Q24ZMLVB&sig=iq0mqL6p_I8ukdLT6Ped_MARBaM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkzMeMpoLNAhXJL8AKHSc6B3gQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20porteira%20o%20que%20lhe%20importa%22&f=false)

> ***A porteira o que lhe importa*** […]

E tive que ir parar a um [serbenfiquista.com/forum](http://serbenfiquista.com/forum/index.php?topic=14908.4675;wap) para encontrar uma destas (grafia original):

> ***eu ninguem me tira*** da cabeça que isto de ganhar musculo vem mto de cada um. ora...um jogador d futebol tem que ter fisico se quer ter o minimo d hipoteses em campeonatos fortes em fisico e ate na diputa de um p um

Isto é alguma figura de estilo? Tem nome?

Comment: Ué!  Usar um pronome pessoal do caso reto em uma frase que ele desempenhe papel de sujeito de alguma oração não seria uma construção não gramática?  Onde você vê esse tipo de construção ainda ser usado atualmente?

Comment: @MarceloVentura Uma das minha citações é de 2013. E eu digo, *eu custa-me a crer*.

Comment: Sim, é bastante comum em Português de Portugal falado, pelo, menos.

Comment: @Duarte Tens [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wjsuAAAAYAAJ&q=%22eu+ningu%C3%A9m+me+quis%22&dq=%22eu+ningu%C3%A9m+me+quis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVsKe29ILNAhXGKMAKHRSEAC0Q6AEIJTAA) um exemplo brasileiro, livro, de 1984: *Eu ninguém me quis*.

Comment: Pra mim, nada mais é do q uma ênfase no sujeito.

Comment: Melhor me parece "eu, custa-me crer", com vírgula, tanto por que fica marcado o fato de o pronome não estar aí como sujeito, tanto por que é assim, creio, que se fala, com uma pausa bem audível.

Comment: @Luís, eu não me parece necessária a vírgula, e o que encontro no Google Books é sem vírgula.

Comment: Talvez seja diferente em Portugal. Aqui no Brasil não me parece que se use "eu custa-me crer", nem com nem sem vírgula. Usa-se sim "eu, ninguém quis", e penso que na linguagem falada geralmente tem uma pausa, embora "eu ninguém quis" também possa ser ouvido.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É uma construção de tópico marcado, em particular **deslocação à esquerda de tópico pendente**, na terminologia da [Gramática de Maria Mateus e outras](http://www.worldcat.org/title/gramatica-da-lingua-portuguesa/oclc/849055253?referer=di&ht=edition) (pág. 493 da 6.ª ed.). Os exemplos aí dados são:

> (11) (a) *O João*… ouvi dizer que e̲l̲e̲ tinha ido passar férias a Honolulu.
>            (b) “… *eu* … medicina privada realmente não m̲e̲ interessa.”

O grau de sintatização é fraco (apenas conformidade de pessoa, género e número) entre o tópico e o constituinte interno ao comentário (respetivamente em itálico e sublinhados); a *Condição de Relevância* («o comentário deve ser relevante acerca do tópico») é satisfeita através de uma correferência conforme nos traços mencionados entre o tópico e o constituinte interno (*idem*).

Contrariamente à outra construção que referes (*a mim custa-me*, uma **deslocação à esquerda clítica**, ver pág. 494-497), apresenta insensibilidade a ilhas e está limitada a frases raiz (factos que sugerem não haver um movimento). Os exemplos dados são estes:

> *O Carreras*… muitas pessoas compraram bilhetes no mercado negro para o̲ ouvirem.
>   */?Toda a gente me disse que *o João* … não l̲h̲e̲ pagaram o ordenado este mês.

Na gramática tradicional, esta construção é geralmente considerada um **anacoluto**, definido por Bechara como «a quebra da estruturação lógica da oração» (*Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*, 37.ª ed., 2006, versão *ebook*, pág. 739) e por Celso e Cunha (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, 1.ª ed., 1984, pág. 624) como «mudança de construção sintática no meio do enunciado, geralmente depois de uma pausa sensível». Bechara dá o exemplo:

> *Eu parece-me* que tudo vai bem.

A Gramática de Celso e Cunha diz simplesmente que «é um fénomeno muito comum, especialmente na linguagem falada», mas Bechara admoesta:

> O anacoluto, fora de certas situações especiais, é evitado pelas
>   pessoas que timbram em falar e escrever corretamente a língua

Comment: Essa da deslocação do tópico, imagino que no (11.a) se pudesse fazer uma deslocação para a direita (*ouvi dizer que ele foi passar férias a Honolulu, o João*), ou para o meio. Na (11.b) não tou a ver que se pudesse deslocar o *eu* para a direita do *me*. Isto faz sentido?

Comment: Ainda parece estranho.  Vejam, o anacoluto ocorre essencialmente quando o orador desiste da formulação original de sua fala logo após ter começado a pronunciá-la e acaba por pronunciar outra formulação da mesma fala.  Daí a tal longa pausa.  Isso é coerente.  Contudo o que ocorre aqui é que a frase já é planejada desde o início dessa forma, sem mudanças de intenção ou de escolha de construção no meio do caminho.   Simplesmente sai o "Eu parece-me" de prima.

Comment: @MarceloVentura Concordo. Por isso me parece que «deslocação à esquerda do tópico pendente» seja uma melhor descrição. Ainda tenho é que ver bem o que isso do tópico pendente.

Comment: @Jacinto O cap. 12 da Gramática do Português é escrito pela mesma pessoa que escreveu o capítulo que referi da Gramática da Língua Portuguesa (Inês Duarte). A construção de deslocação à esqda de tópico pendente aparece em §12.2.2.1.

Comment: @MarceloVentura Não vejo nada na pergunta (poderá o Jacinto esclarecer) que indique que não há pausa ou entoação diferente no tópico. É verdade que nenhuma das frases tem pontuação, mas acho que estás a ler demais nisso. Dificilmente vejo "_eu_ parece-me que isso não é verdade" a ser lido como "_ele_ parece doente", sem entoação. De resto, _eu parece-me_ é tratado como uma construção de tópico [aqui](http://www.inventario.ufba.br/04/04earaujo.htm) (sob _tópico pendente_) e [aqui](http://www.meertens.knaw.nl/projecten/edisyn/Online_proceedings/Paper_Carrilho.pdf), por exemplo.

Comment: @Jacinto Sobre a "deslocação à direita" vê §12.3 (_Conceito de contratópico_). No meio não estou a ver como pode servir para focar um tópico. Poderia sim funcionar como um aposto.

Comment: Eu creio que em certas expressões, como *eu custa-me a crer/aceitar/etc.*, não há grande pausa. Não tenho a certeza se ***eu custa-me** a crer* soa como *o m**eu custa-me** €10 por mês*. Mas parece-me, e creio que esse é o ponto principal do @Marcelo , que *eu custa-me* e outras que tais são expressões fixas: não resultam que eu começar a dizer uma coisa e mudar de ideias a meio do enunciado.

Comment: @Jacinto Nenhuma das definições que dei fala em "mudar de ideias".

Comment: Não, foi como o @Marcelo interpretou anacoluto no comentário dele acima. E é até tentador ler essa interpretação na definição do Celso Cunha.