# Regência de «custar»: «custa-me a crer» versus «custa-me crer»

Tags: sintaxe, preposições, regência-verbal

Com alguns verbos, eu claramente prefiro ***custa-me a***:

> (a) Custa-me **a** crer nisso (em vez de *custa-me crer nisso*)
>   (b) Custa-me **a** respirar com este calor

Com outros, prefiro simplesmente ***custa-me***, sem o ***a***:

> (c) Custa-me dizer-lhe que não
>   (d) Custa-me deixá-lo sozinho

Fui ver se seria só mania minha, mas parece que há aqui mesmo qualquer coisas. Embora os números, mesmo os de Portugal, não espelhem exatamente as minha preferências, em ambos os países a propensão a usar o ***a*** é claramente maior nos verbos em que eu o usaria do que nos outros.

**Resultados da busca no Google**

```
                              Google geral                            Google Books
                   Portugal                   Brasil                 todos os países
          Custa-me a   Custa-me      Custa-me a   Custa-me         Custa-me a   Custa-me
crer          227         71             131        237               24/19*     22/6*
respirar       35         50              17         23               21         10
dizer          13        140               1        117                3         13
deixar          1         78               2         32                3         10

* Nota: 19 contra 6 se excluirmos gramáticas; parece que todas elas usaram o verbo “crer” 
para ilustrar estas regências de “custar”.
```

Ao que parece eu falo à Machado de Assis:

> Eu sei? **custa-me a crer** no amor.
>   [Machado de Assis, *Contos Fluminenses*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tY9cAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT107&dq=%22Custa-me%20a%20crer%20no%20amor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV17fTmbrjAhUAA2MBHSb9BVoQ6AEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=%22Custa-me%20a%20crer%20no%20amor%22&f=false)
>
> **Custa-me dizer** isto, mas antes peque por excessivo que por diminuto.
>   [Machado de Assis, *Dom Casmurro*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hrRCDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&dq=%22Custa-me%20dizer%20isto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTmInRmrrjAhUx0uAKHV0AByEQ6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=%22Custa-me%20dizer%20isto%22&f=false)

Atualização. Edite Prada no [Ciberdúvdas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-regencia-do-verbo-custar/12972) reconhece estas duas regências, dizendo que “[o] uso ou não da preposição parece estar relacionado com o verbo que ocorre na frase infinitiva e com as suas características lexicais”, o que não nos diz muito.

**A questão então é:** porque é que tendemos a usar este ***a*** mais com uns verbos do que com outros? Que propriedades do verbo favorece o uso do ***a***? Que faz o ***a*** neste tipo de frases?

Comment: Eu talvez só usa-se o *a* no primeiro exemplo. E "Custa-me a dizer-lhe que não" não me parece nada gramatical... Uma boa pergunta!

Comment: @JorgeB. Também não digo *custa-me a dizer;* mas *custa-me crer* soa-me ainda pior.

Comment: A forma recomendada por gramáticos é "custa-me crer", e "custa-me a crer" é dita ser aceitável.  Já "eu custo a crer" é certamente errado. Eu diria que "custa-me a crer" tornou-se idiomático e, por esse motivo, passou a ser considerado aceitável por gramáticos.  Eu, pessoalmente, digo "custa-me a crer" e acredito ser a forma mais prevalente em pt-BR.  Mas ouço muita gente dizer "eu custo a crer" e "eu custo a acreditar" e acredito que esse uso de custar não tenha o significado de "ter um preço" e sim "demorar", i.e., "levo tempo para acreditar".  É a forma como entendo, não é uma resposta.

Comment: @Centaurus Ainda bem que *custa-me a crer* é a forma prevalente no Brasil também. *Custa-me crer* não me soa nada bem. Parece-me até que o 3-a-1 para o *custa-me a crer* em Portugal é pouco. Os melhores autores escreveram *custa-me a crer*, Machado de Assis, José de Alencar, etc. Que gramáticos é que recomendam *custa-me crer*? Se nós usamos o ***a*** com uns verbos e não com outros, o ***a*** deve desempenhar uma função expressiva qualquer.

Comment: Acho que "custa-me crer", da forma como eu pronunciaria soa como um cacófato: "custa mecrer", embora não exista a palavra "mecrer". Acho que o "a" serve para formar um hiato.  Calma, eu disse acho.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu também pronunciaria como *custa mecrer*, mas *custa-me a crer*, pronuncio como *custa macrer*, que não me parece melhorar grande coisa.

Answer (score 1):

De fato, é curioso. Em tese, o que está em questão é a regência de custar; os outros verbos não deveriam em absoluto influenciar o uso da preposição. Mas se os dados que você coloca têm alguma relevância estatística, parece que influenciam. Mais em Portugal, aparentemente, onde "custa-me a crer" é inclusive majoritário.

Essa diferença entre Brasil e Portugal talvez tenha a ver com uma tendência maior do português do Brasil a elidir partículas. Mas não me ocorre nenhuma explicação razoável para a diferença entre "crer" e os outros verbos, a não ser uma talvez improvável analogia com "acreditar":

> Custa-me acreditar

Talvez percebido como

> Custa-me a creditar

Donde

> Custa-me a creditar => Custa-me a crer

Mas é puro chute.

Comment: É capaz de ser um bom chute... Mas agora é preciso provar ;)

Comment: Eu uso a preposição ***a*** mesmo com *acreditar*. No meu sotaque a pronúncia de *me acreditar* é diferente da de *me a acreditar*: /m***ɐ***kɾɨdi’taɾ/ versus /m***a***kɾɨdi’taɾ/.

Comment: @Jacinto - então não deve ser. Outra coisa que me ocorre é que *crer* e *respirar* são (ou podem ser) intransitivos, enquanto *dizer* e *deixar* exigem complemento. Será mais natural dizer *custa-me a crer!* do que *custa-me a crer no milagre da transubstanciação*?

Comment: Talvez, mas «custa-me a crer no amor» (Machado de Assis), «Custa-me a crer que um homem se case» (idem), «custa-me a crer em tamanha felicidade» (Bernardo Guimarães), [«custa-me a crer taes boatos»](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/que-faz-o-eu-em-eu-custa-me-a-crer-tais-boatos-ou-nem-sequer-l%C3%A1-devia-estar) (Revista do IHGRGS).

Comment: @Jacinto não sei se percebeste mas é "a [creditar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-creditar)" e não "a acreditar"... Ou eu é que percebi mal...

Comment: Pois é curioso. _Custa-me a crer_ parece-me bem, mas _custa-me muito a crer nisso_ já me parece um pouco estranho (parece-me melhor _custa-me muito crer nisso_). O dicionário de regências de Francisco Fernandes diz que o bom uso manda a omissão de _a_ mas que exemplos com _a_ se encontram nos melhores escritores. A Grande Enciclopédia Portuguesa e Brasileira manda-nos para Factos da Linguagem de Heráclito Graça (dificil de encontrar em Portugal) e Problemas da linguagem de Cândido de Figueiredo (que está na biblioteca da FLUL por exemplo).