# "Eu que lute" está gramaticalmente correto?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu, modo-subjuntivo

"Eu que lute" é uma expressão que está sendo utilizada no Brasil. Ela significa que o problema é do falante, e que ele deve se esforçar para resolve-lo sozinho.

Eu estou na dúvida se esse é um uso correto do modo subjuntivo/conjuntivo, já que "que eu lute" me parece ser a forma correta.

Comment: Espero bem que esteja. Eu uso esse tipo de construção a toda a hora. Muito comum em Portugal: *ele que se despache, que eu não espero; eles que se entendam; comeram tudo, e eu que me lixe*. Deve haver um nome para isto.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu acredito que o significado seja o mesmo de "que ele se despache", expressa um desejo. Mas me parece que essa construção tem uma nuance de "não é problema meu".

Comment: Herbert, exato: *ele que o faça se quiser, por eu não quero saber disso para nada*.

Comment: https://www.beeshirts.com.br/produtos/eu-que-lute/ Isso para mim é uma variante do conhecido: Que se [verbo subjuntivo], [pronome]. Que [eles] se danem. Ele que se despache. é: Que ele se despache. Ou: que se despache ele. É uma inversão da estrutura tradicional. Que lutem [elas] para ter um bumbum como um modelo. Ou: que o faça ele.

Comment: Concordo com os comentários anteriores. É difícil imaginar que algo como "eles que se virem" seja incorreto, parece ser uma mera mudança da ordem que, sim, pela maior ênfase no sujeito, pode trazer uma conotação menos de desejo meu e mais de "problema dos outros".

Comment: @stafusa. O negócio é o seguinte: Se eu te dizer: "eles que se virem", já estavamos conversando sobre um assunto. Também,  é uma forma falada, não escrita. O estranho no "Eu que lute" é que normalmente esse subjuntivo não se ouvre com a primeira pessoa do singular.

Comment: @Lambie. Agreed.

Answer (score 5):

A ordem natural é *que* + sujeito + verbo + objeto + complemento, como em «que ele envie uma carta para mim!»; assim, a frase na ordem direta seria «que eu lute». Então, antecipamos *eu* na frase, dizendo «eu que lute», ganhando ênfase, o que se chama [antecipação](https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/analepse-e-prolepse/) ou prolepse. Isto é comum na literatura de histórias e muito na língua falada que conheço.

O escritor Machado de Assis fez algo semelhante:

> [...] melhor é afrouxar a rédea à pena, e **ela que vá andando**, até achar entrada.

Comment: Isto não está de acordo com as definições de *anástrofe, hipérbato* e *sinquise* no Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra. Tens [um resumo aqui](https://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap17-02-figuras_de_sintaxe). Quando muito seria um hipérbato em sentido lato, mas mesmo aí é "inversão da ordem normal das palavras na oração", e parece-me que em "ela que vá andando", o *ela* já saiu da própria oração. Poderá ser uma prolepse.

Comment: @Jacinto, obrigado Jacinto pelo comentário. Não tenho certeza, mas, em «Os pastores parece que vivem no fim do mundo!», ouço chamar *os pastores* e depois falar deles, enquanto, em «Eu que lute», não ouço chamamento, apenas *eu* deslocado, ou seja, não me parece que *eu* seja doutra oração. Se ouves diferente, seria bom ter uma resposta tua.

Comment: Não é uma questão de ouvir. No conjuntivo independente, a oração começa com o *que*. Na outra, *os pastores* também não é oração nenhuma: não há la verbo nenhum; há uma oração subordinante, *parece*, e uma subordinada, *que vivem*... *pastores* é algo à parte. De qualquer modo, em *que eu lute*, *eu* não é complemento (ou determinante, como lhe chama Celso Cunha) de *que*, portanto não é anástrofe, de acordo a com a definição deles. Nota que a fronteira duma oração não tem de ser marcada por pausa. Por exemplo, em *ele diz que vem* há duas orações.

Comment: @Jacinto, acho que agora entendi o que quiseste dizer e o que diz o livro — eu confundi o significado de *preceder*. Agora que entendi, concordo. Vou mudar a pergunta depois. Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda bem, mas agora sou eu que não te compreendo: "significado de *preceder*"?! Qual *preceder*? Quiseste dizer *parecer*? As explicações da Flávia Neves (site que tu linkas) parecem-me enganadoras. O Celso Cunha dá significados precisos a *anástrofe* e *hipérbato* -- não diz que são apenas meros graus na complicação da alteração da ordem normal. Eu estou em crer que na linguística moderna, isto é um caso de tópico marcado: vê o [eu custa-me a crer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/que-faz-o-eu-em-eu-custa-me-a-crer-tais-boatos-ou-nem-sequer-l%c3%a1-devia-estar).

Comment: @Jacinto, desculpa. Eu tinha me esquecido completamente de te responder e da resposta.